# BackboneJs how to loop through collection get specific value from each model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, iframe

I have a Backbone Collection where I want to get a specific value from each model and then insert that value into an Iframe.

So, I have multiple Iframe's, where I want to insert the data-src dynamically, the basic code for the iframe is:

```
<iframe class="playlist" data-src=""></iframe>
```

and my Backbone Code:

```
this.collection.each(function(spotify) {
    var service = spotify.get('services').spotify;
    var spotifyplayId = service.substr(service.lastIndexOf('/') +1);
    console.log(spotifyplayId)
    $('iframe.playlist').each(function(spotifyplayId) {
        $(this).attr('data-src', 'https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:digster.dk:playlist:'+ spotifyplayId);
    });
});
```

the `console.log(spotifyplayId)` gives me the correct data, only the dynamic insert into the Iframes fails. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
this.collection.each(function(spotify, index) {
    var service       = spotify.get('services').spotify,
        spotifyplayId = service.substr(service.lastIndexOf('/') +1);

    $('iframe.playlist').eq(index).attr('data-src', 'https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:digster.dk:playlist:' + spotifyplayId);
});
```

Because in your example `spotifyplayId` is index (0, 1, 2) in loop, but you need get `spotifyplayId` from parent scope. And in our case better use [.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `$.each`.

Comment: @Steve I've updated example. As I understood you have same length this.collection and $('iframe.playlist'). If in collection there are 5 items in page also there are 5 iframes... Is it correct ?

Comment: @Steve as you can see I've added new example

Comment: Now we're at it, I found out that in some cases I need to use `lastIndexOf(':')+1` - How can I include this check the best way?

Comment: Hmm, still it doesnt get the `lastIndexOf(':')+1` :-s - I like the approach though...